# ajax.actionlink calling a controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

If I am using an Ajax.ActionLink helper, and I need to pass a couple parameters to the controller action, how can I get the value of a TextArea that is not bound to a model?

For instance, I want the user to fill out a textarea, and then click Save, sending the textarea value to the controller action for further processing.

Do I use ViewBag? If so, how do I assign the value of a DOM element to ViewBag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag is a server-side concept. It does not exist once the page has been rendered.
There is no way that I know of to declaratively link a field on the page with an action parameter.

To do what you want you have two options:
- get rid of the Ajax.ActionLink helper, and write some Javascript (sorry, Ican't really help you there)
- Use to Ajax.BeginForm instead and put the relevant fields in the form, so that a click on the submit button will submit the form back to your action through ajax.

Comment: @Dennis Troller - thanks for you help. I will use js instead. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've toyed with this problem before, and you can get around it by using `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Take this follow example:

I have a model `Person` that one string property for Name.

**View**

```
@model Application.Models.Person

<fieldset>
    <legend>Form</legend>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendUp", "Home", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnComplete = "window.location.href = 'Index'"
    }))
    {  
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.TextArea("ta")
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    }
</fieldset>
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendUp(string Name, string ta)
    {
        string s = ta;
        // Process stuff here
        // Go to another action or whatever
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Using `Ajax.BeginForm()` allows you to send data up to the controller *even if it not bound to a model on the page*. You need to make sure that the `name` property of your Html element is the same name as the parameter that the controller needs.

So if you have the controller method of

```
public ActionResult SendUp(string Name, string ta)
```

You will need to have an Html element of with the name `Name` and `ta` inside of the `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

To do this you can either write out the entire element:

```
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />
```

Or you can use the `@Html` helpers.

```
@Html.Editor("Name")
```

When you provide the name for the @Html helper it will set that value to as the `id` property and to the `name` property as well.